# Array throwing exception

Tags: arrays, libgdx

I can't seem to put my finger on this and why the array is not being initialized.

Basically I am coding a 2d top down spaceship game and the ship is going to be fully customizable. The ship has several allocated slots for certain "Modules" (ie weapons, electronic systems) and these are stored in an array as follows:

```
protected Array<Weapon> weaponMount;
```

Upon creating the ship none of the module arrays are initialized, since some ships might have 1 weapon slot, while others have 4.

So when I code new ships, like this example:

```
public RookieShip(World world, Vector2 position) {

    this.width = 35;
    this.height = 15;

    // Setup ships model
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(position);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    chassis.setAsBox(width / GameScreen.WORLD_TO_BOX_WIDTH, height / GameScreen.WORLD_TO_BOX_HEIGHT);
    fixtureDef.shape = chassis;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.225f;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.85f;

    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/TestShip.png")));
    body.setUserData(sprite);

    chassis.dispose();

    // Ship module properties
    setShipName("Rookie Ship"); 
    setCpu(50);
    setPower(25);
    setFuel(500);

    setWeaponMounts(2, world);
    setDefenseSlots(1);

    addModule(new BasicEngine(), this);
    addModule(new BasicBlaster(), this);

    // Add hp
    setHullHP(50);
    setArmorHP(125);
    setShieldHP(125);

}

@Override
public void addModule(Module module, Ship currentShip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addModule(module, currentShip);
}

@Override
public void setWeaponMounts(int weaponMounts, World world) {
    weaponMount = new Array<Weapon>(weaponMounts);
//      super.setWeaponMounts(weaponMounts, world);
}

@Override
public String displayInfo() {
    String info = "Everyones first ship, sturdy, reliable and only a little bit shit";

    return info;

}
```

When I set the number of weapon mounts the following method is called:

```
    public void setWeaponMounts(int weaponMounts, World world) {
    weaponMount = new Array<Weapon>(weaponMounts);      
}
```

This basically initializes the array with a size (weapon mounts available) to whatever the argument is. Now to me this seems fine but I have setup a hotkey to output the size of the Array, which reports zero. If I try to reference any objects in the array, it throws an outofbounds exception.

The addModule method adds to the array as follows:

```
    public void addModule(Module module, Ship currentShip) {
    currentShip.cpu -= module.getCpuUsage();
    currentShip.power -= module.getPowerUsage();
    if(module instanceof Engine){
        engine = (Engine) module;
    }else if(module instanceof Weapon){
        if(maxWeaponMounts == weaponMount.size){
            System.out.println("No more room for weapons!");
        }else{
        maxWeaponMounts += 1;
        weaponMount.add((Weapon)module);
        }
    }

}
```

My coding ain't great but heh, better than what I was 2 month ago....

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a Libgdx Array or a standard Java Array?  Also, you should show the code that triggers the exception and the exception itself.

Comment: It is a Libgdx array and it was just me derping! Well sort of, the below poster suggested some changes to my code so I will do that before I go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You should avoid `instanceof`. It's not a really big deal performance-wise, but it always points to problems with your general architecture. Implement two different `addModule` methods. One that takes a Weapon, and one that takes an Engine.

Now back to topic:

```
else if(module instanceof Weapon){
    if (maxWeaponMounts == weaponMount.size) {
        System.out.println("No more room for weapons!");
    } else{
       maxWeaponMounts += 1;
       weaponMount.add((Weapon)module);
    }
}
```

It looks like you use maxWeaponMounts as a counter instead of a limit. That's why I assume that it will initially be 0. The same holds for `Array.size`. It is not the limit, but `size` also counts how many elements the `Array` currently holds. Thus you will always have `(maxWeaponMounts == weaponMount.size)` as `0 == 0` and you will not add the weapon to the array. It will always stay empty and trying to reference any index will end in an `OutOfBoundsException`.

What you should actually do is using `maxWeaponMounts` as a fixed limit and not the counter.

```
public void setWeaponMounts(int weaponMounts, World world) {
    weaponMount = new Array<Weapon>(weaponMounts);
    maxWeaponMounts = weaponMounts;
}

else if(module instanceof Weapon){
    if (weaponMount.size >= maxWeaponMounts) {
        System.out.println("No more room for weapons!");
    } else{
       weaponMount.add((Weapon)module);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had something similar to this before I changed it, funny enough I can't remember testing it but I think it had a problem. Will refactor code and try now. However if I put a print method in the else statement where it adds the weapon to the array, it outputs confirming that part of the code actually got executed. So I should just implement a new method, use overloading and change the arguement?

Comment: OMG, such a tool. I must have accidently overrided the superclass method in my rookie ship, resulting in the array and maxWeapon mounts never being set....it is amazing what you notice after asking a question and get a sleep lol!